# Dragon Age Origins Ultimate Edition not saving

Tags: dragon-age-origins, dragon-age-origins-awakening

I've installed Dragon Age Origins Ultimate Edition in my PC (Windows 10). The installation was successful and the game works fine. I saved and quit the game after playing 1 hour. When I again launched the game, I found there is no save happened and I verified the Characters Folder inside Bioware in My Documents. The folder is created with my character name and inside there is Saves and inside it there are  Autosave_1 & slot_1 Folders but all the folders are empty.
There are full permission for the folders too.

Tried reinstalling/restarting multiple times. Did not work. When I search in internet, they say it might be due to permission Issue, but full control is given for all folders .

Please help me to resolve the Issue.

Comment: Did you install it through Steam?

Comment: Please specify whether you have a disk, origin, steam or gog version. Did you try starting the game as an administrator?

Comment: I've gog version. Inside the game it says saving whenever i Save, but the saves folder and it's subfolders are always empty. Yes, I started the game as administrator also, it Does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi The problem got resolved. MY Bit Defender Antivirus was protecting the folder "MyDocuments"which does not allows Dragon age to save this. I removed this controlled access folder permission in my Bit Defender and the game saves successfully.